# TikTok api user/info/ endpoint return error code 6007063

Tags: c#, api, request, tiktok

I implemented TikTok PI and everything works well. In the last days I encountered a problem that the `user/info/` endpoint returns `'error code': '6007063', 'message': 'auth user info is required'`. This is happening for some of the accounts while others succeeded (there is nothing different between the accounts), I guess it's on tiktok side.

```
var Client = new HttpClient();
var userDataRequest = new UserDataRequest
{
    open_id = tokenObj.data.open_id,
    access_token = tokenObj.data.access_token,
    fields = new HashSet<string> { "open_id", "union_id", "avatar_url", "avatar_url_100", "avatar_url_200", "avatar_large_url", "display_name" }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userDataRequest);
var body = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await Client.PostAsync("https://open-api.tiktok.com/user/info/", body).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

How can I solve the problem and what does this error mean?

https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-user-info-basic

Comment: you haven't posted any code.

Comment: Hi,
It's just http call for this endpoint with the relevant parameters as specified in tiktok documnetion.

Comment: and you did the http call without any code?

Comment: Same issue here, I believe it's on the TikTok side.

Comment: @LiadCohen did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @JérômeMahuet Yes, the data should be transfer in the query param and not in the body. It's relevant also for access token and refresh token.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and I found that the way I refresh the access token is incorrect. POST https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/refresh_token/

For this API, we should put client_key, grant_type, and refresh_token in the query instead of in the body or post data.
POST [https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/refresh_token/?client_key={my_client_key}&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={my_client_token}](https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/refresh_token/?client_key=%7Bmy_client_key%7D&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=%7Bmy_client_token%7D)

This solves my problem. Maybe you could check the way you refresh your access token to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, all data should be in the link, and not in the body of the request. And then when receiving a token by reference https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/access_token/ it works correctly when using it further

Doc: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-manage-user-access-tokens/

```
let url_access_token = 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/access_token/';
    url_access_token += '?client_key=' + CLIENT_KEY;
    url_access_token += '&client_secret=' + CLIENT_SECRET;
    url_access_token += '&code=' + code;
    url_access_token += '&grant_type=authorization_code';
```